# Como passar esta variável para o escopo?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factorys

```
(function () {
    angular.module("Hawking").controller('loginController', function ($log, $scope, validateUser) {

        var dataUser = { email: "RAFAEL.NOGEUIRA2@GMAIL.COM", senha: "123456" };


        validateUser.getUser(dataUser).then(function(data){
            console.log(data); // ok!
            $scope.data = data;
        });


        console.log($scope.data); // undefined 
    })
        .factory('validateUser', function ($http, $q) {
            return {
                getUser: function (userInfo) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    var status = {
                            id_usuario: null,
                            permission: false
                    };
                     $http.get('/hawkingBE/api/usuarios/').then(function (response) {
                        angular.forEach(response.data, function (value, key) {
                            if (value.email == userInfo.email && value.senha == userInfo.senha) {
                                status = {
                                    id_usuario: value.id_usuario,
                                    permission: true
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    deferred.resolve(status);
                    return deferred.promise;
                }
            }
        });
})();
```

Comment: Já tentou declarar e inicializar o `$scope.data` fora da função `getUser`?

Answer (score 0):

O javascript é assíncrono. Ou seja.. na pilha de execução do javascript a variável `$scope.data` não está definida. Só então ao resolver a promise da factory ela será atribuída para a variável desejada, ou seja, não há forma de passar este escopo pois não é síncrono.